# How to parse an XML response using Runscope

Tags: javascript, xml, runscope

I have been using Runscope default library "marknote XML Parser" to parse XML documents. In all the endpoints so far it was working well. However in the new endpoint I am trying to parse it is parsing a null object. This is the code I am using:

```
var parser = new marknote.Parser();
var doc = parser.parse(response.body);
```

The thing is, when I try the information using the 'XML body' assertions of Runscope using X-path it works like a charm, but when I use the library it does not parse.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you send us a link to a test result's Shareable URL (toggle top right when viewing the result) to help@runscope.com we'll be happy to take a look in more detail.

Comment: Thanks, I just sent the email